# SwiftUI - @Published var not working but local variable works

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this class

```
class StoreWrapper:ObservableObject {
    @Published var displaySpinner: Bool = true
}
```

and I am trying to use this var to control the visibility of a spinner on ContentView, like this

CONTENT VIEW

```
private var storeWrapper = StoreWrapper.sharedInstance

var body: some View {
  if storeWrapper.displaySpinner {
    Spinner()
  }
```

I can change the displaySpinner variable to false and the spinner will not hide.

But if I do this:

CONTENT VIEW

```
@State var displaySpinner = true
var body: some View {
  if displaySpinner {
    Spinner()
  }
```

and change displaySpinner to false, the spinner will hide.

Any ideas?

Comment: It’s probably related to how your ObservableObject gets initialised. Could you share all of your ContentView code please?

Comment: I have added the part whre storeWrapper gets initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@StateObject` to watch the property. Here's the example I set up to test it.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var displayWrapper = StoreWrapper()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if displayWrapper.displaySpinner {
            Text("I'm spinning")
        } else {
            Text("No spins here.")
        }
        Button("Toggle Spinner") {
            displayWrapper.displaySpinner.toggle()
        }

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the View know that the storeWrapper is an observed object.
This line:

```
private var storeWrapper = StoreWrapper.sharedInstance
```

should be:

```
@ObservedObject private var storeWrapper = StoreWrapper.sharedInstance
```

Comment: I changed as you say, problem continues. Very strange.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that toggles the spinner, so it's not possible to help further.